# How can I delete a folder from my WebMatrix project?

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix

The default setup for a project in WebMatrix contains an "Account" folder with many files such as Login.cshtml, Logout.cshtml, Register.cshtml, etc.

I do not need/want login capability for the site I'm currently building. So, I removed references to such in the various pages, but when I try to delete the folder itself, the screen flashes but nothing seems to happen.

So how can I get rid of this unneeded "baggage"? The same goes for StarterSite.sdf - trying to delete it just causes a "screen flash" but the file remains intransically barnacled into place.

### UPDATE

Note: I am going to bountify this question for 50 points ASAP. If I get an answer prior to that, I will award the bounty post-answer.

I can open the project in Visual Studio and delete things just fine...is that really the expected workaround?

Comment: I would like to get this much working for you, as well, if I can. Are you still having issues with this? (Also, I have updated my answer for more detailed information).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are saying shouldn't occur in WebMatrix. You can always browse to the location of your sites using Windows Explorer (default location is `My Documents/My Web Sites`), however WebMatrix's interface should allow you to delete folders and files just fine (I've never had any problems with it).

The solution for you is probably just gonna end up being uninstall/reinstall WebMatrix (don't forget to backup your sites from above-stated location!). I don't personally know how else you can handle that issue.

If you don't want to do a reinstall, then just browse to your "My Documents" folder and then your "My Web Sites" folder and delete it there. After you've done that, go back to WebMatrix and select the uppermost folder (it will be named with your site name) in the left pane (where your site directory tree is shown) and tap `f5` to refresh the view. Let me know if either approach helps you :)

Comment: I just deleted it in Visual Studio.

Comment: @ClayShannon Did I help? Could you get it working? Did you try reinstalling WebMatrix? I bet that would fix it.