# Why is my WebMatrix project still using the old favicon.ico file?

Tags: html, jpeg, webmatrix, favicon, ico

The default favicon.ico that gets included in a WebMatrix product is added in _SiteLayout.cshtml like so:

```
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

That icon does not fit my app, so I converted a jpg I created at http://www.coolutils.com/Online/Image-Converter/.

I renamed favicon.ico to *YourMotherWearsCombatBoots.ico* and renamed the image I had 
converted to favicon.ico (after adding it to my project).

I thought that my new .ico file would get used in the browser's tab for the page/site. But, alas, no! The old .ico file is making like the Raven of Poe's poem - it simply will nevermore go away. What's up with that?

### UPDATE

Note: If trying this out using firefox or IE as the browser doesn't work (currently testing with Chrome), I am going to bountify this question for 50 points ASAP. If I get an answer prior to that, I will award the bounty post-answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the cache :)

As long as the path to the file (including the filename) is correct, and it is a .ico file, it should render.

That having been said, try not using `~` maybe, since it is only an html tag and it uses `/` to find the root of the site.

I've done this many many times, and never had any issue with any ico in any browser.

Honestly the cache is the only thing I can think of.

**----------------------------------UPDATE----------------------------------**

I'm expanding my answer to show an example. This is a scenario I have just recently set up and it worked perfect first time (as it does for me every time).

**The HTML:**

```
<link href="/Images/Site_Icon/Scribe.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

**The Directory Structure:**

[image: directory structure for "Scribe.ico"]

**The Result:**

[image]

Since I've been using icons for my sites, I have not noticed that there need be anything else. As far as I know this is all that should be involved with getting this to work as expected.

If this still does not help, do the following:

1. Re-verify the path, check it one folder at a time.
2. Delete the old Microsoft favicon entirely, unless you plan on using it for something else (which I doubt).
3. Open the ico file you are trying to render. Is it really the picture you expect it to be?
4. Manually `(Ctrl+Shift+Del)` clear the cache (especially for Chrome) and try again (if you're gonna debug in Chrome, you might as well get used to doing this regularly [okay, actually it doesn't matter what browser you use, you'll always have to do this when something doesn't render the way you expect, so that you'll know it's not a caching issue]).
5. Make sure you're looking at the right site, when it's open in your browser (i.e., make sure that you're not editing your site locally and pulling a non-updated version from your server or something).

Other than that, I can't think of anything else it could be.

Comment: I open the default.cshtml with the Browser of my choice (Chrome), mash Ctrl+R to "Refresh" (that's what you mean by "clearing the cache," right?), but the MS-Word-looking ico still displays in my web site's tab...

Comment: @ClayShannon Well, actually you can mash Ctrl+f5 or you can just use Ctrl+Shift+Del to bring up the interface and do it manually, but if this isn't helping, I would verify the path exactly. Did you remove the tilde `(~)` from the path to your ico? If it is showing the wrong icon, it must be either caching it or getting it from somewhere. I'm sure you've tried verifying this path many times, but, if the path is correct, it should work. Also, why rename the favicon.ico when you can just delete it if you're not gonna use it. You don't need it for anything.

Comment: I'm expanding my answer to show an example of the html and directory structure to an ico file from a site I just recently set up. It worked the first time and my sites always start with that Microsoft favicon, just like yours.

Comment: As to deleting the no-longer-wanted icon - that's a no go, too, in WebMatrix - I've tried deleting files and folders (I have an SO post about this, in fact) and I see a "flash," but nothing is actually deleted.

Comment: That post about not being able to delete in WebMatrix is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138043/how-can-i-delete-a-folder-from-my-webmatrix-project

Comment: @ClayShannon I saw your post. You know you can browse to the location on your sites in explorer right? You don't have to use WebMatrix's interface for that, however, you *should* be able to use it. That having been said, what I think you might need to do (for both this issue and the other one) is uninstall and reinstall WebMatrix.

Comment: I'm always wary about messing with projects from outside the project environment. I might just switch to using VS2012, even though there are some advantages to WebMatrix for this type of project.

Comment: @ClayShannon Honestly, I've used WebMatrix a lot and there really might be something wrong with your install somehow (it is starting to look that way, esp. from your other post). I really think you'll be happy with it if you uninstall/reinstall.  And don't worry about messing with the project from outside of WebMatrix. Whatever folders are there in the site, it will find, it won't break anything to backup your site, reinstall WebMatrix, re-get helpers, and then either open site from folder (the one you backed up) or create new site (with same name) and just paste all the contents in.

Comment: I've opened the project in VS2012, and the same problem persists. I have deleted the old icon, now, too, so where it's getting it/how it's embedded like a barnacle, I don't know. I just checked, and it works fine in Firefox and IE - it's just Chrome that retains that Wonder-Bread-looking icon.

Comment: Did you take all of the necessary steps I stated above? If you followed all of my suggestions (clear cache, and NOT just refresh, remove the tilde `~` from your path in your html file, double checked the picture to make sure it is the image you expect, etc.) and it is still persisting, you might want to call a priest, as you must have a poltergeist :) lol

Comment: The one thing I haven't done is clear the cache, because of all the scary things it said it would do if I did - wipe out my bookmarks, turn princesses into frogs, etc. Since it works on other browsers, I'm not too worried about it right now.

Comment: Okay, well let me start by saying this: As a web developer, get used to clearing the cache. All you are doing when you clear the cache is telling the browser to stop loading the files as it last remembers them and actually download the information from the files again (thus forcing it to look at your new markup/styles/scripts). The cache is only there to help "speed up" your browser, so it doesn't load the same files over and over again. As a developer, you might as well get used to clearing the cache (the shortcut is Ctrl+Shift+Del, for IE, Chrome, FF, and probably Opera and Safari, too)...

Comment: That having been said, there are some settings in the window you will get just before you are about to clear the cache. So, keep the cookies, if in IE make sure to un-check the box that "preserves data", and in fact you only really need it to do one thing which the browser will describe as actually "clearing the cache". Things clearing the cache will NOT do: Delete your bookmarks. I don't know who told you it would, but they are wrong. I ALWAYS clear the cache in any browser before I reload changes. It's just habit at this point. Also the most notorious browser for keeping cache IS Chrome...

Comment: In short: There is NOTHING wrong with clearing the cache. In fact, overtime the cache clears itself, whether you want it to or not. In Chrome's cache window (once you've hit Ctrl+Shift+Del), you will see a bunch of check-box options. The ONLY one you really need checked is the option that reads, "Empty the cache." This will not damage, hinder, break, or delete anything you can't get back by subsequently reloading the page. This IS what you want it to do, i.e., forget what it remembers last about the site, and instead, load a fresh copy. How else can you be sure it's loading your new changes?

Comment: @ClayShannon Did you get it working? Can I be of any further help on this matter? (Saw the awarded bounty, and just want to make sure I've done my part to get it working for you).

Comment: @ClayShannon One more thing, I feel I never quite explained was when TO use the tilde (`~`). When using C#, you do want to use the tilde (e.g., `Response.Redirect("~/")` would be your default home page). Or if you want to start at the root and browse elsewhere: `Response.Redirect("~/someDir/AnotherDir/someFile.cshtml")`. Pretty much when using C# code, just use `~/` instead of only `/`

Comment: Thanks, VoidKing, just what I needed to know. I will clear the cache just like my wife clears my cash when I get home (just joking, honey).

Comment: @ClayShannon LOL, nice! Well, in that case, I certainly hope you get it working, so you can clear your cache to make more cash for your wife to clear :)

Comment: I just cleared the cache, and deleted the last day; no change. I then cleared again, for a week; still no change. Ah! Wrote too soon - now it changed to "my" icon. Good. All's well that ends well.

Comment: @ClayShannon Just to let you know, when you clear the cache, just do it from "the beginning of time". Again, you're not gonna break anything, especially if "empty the cache" is the only checkbox ticked.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely an issue with the browser rather than anything to do with WebMatrix or code.